# React typescript type 'FC<{....}>' does not satisfy 'FC<{}>'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-generics

```
import * as React from "react";

const Input: React.FC<{ abc: string }> = props => {
  return <input />;
};

const F = <T extends React.FC>(
  props: React.PropsWithChildren<
    { Component: T; a: string; b: boolean; c: object } & Parameters<T>[0]
  >
) => {
  const { Component, a, b, c, ...other } = props as { Component: React.FC<any> };
  return <Component {...other } />;
};

export default function App() {
  return <F Component={Input} abc='123'/>;
}
```

this is the error message

```
Type 'FC<{ required: string; }>' is not assignable to type 'FC<{}>'.
  Types of parameters 'props' and 'props' are incompatible.
    Type '{ children?: ReactNode; }' is not assignable to type 'PropsWithChildren<{ required: string; }>'.
      Property 'required' is missing in type '{ children?: ReactNode; }' but required in type '{ required: string; }'
```

this happens if the Input element has required props, in this case, the `abc` props

the solution that I tried:

solution 1:

the error disappears if I change `<T extends React.FC>` to `<T extends React.FC<any>>`

this change my `props` type to `any` due to `& Parameters<T>[0]`

still, I can solve this by typecast the props

2nd solution is I change `<T extends React.FC>` to `<T extends typeof Input>`

=============================================================================

I have 2 questions

I don't like solution 1 because I need to typecast it, I think this is not a "proper" way of doing it

I think solution 2 is good but it become weird if I union it with more component, eg `<T extends typeof Input|typeof Input2>`

so the first question, what is the proper way to solve this

the second question, help me to understand why the error?

here is the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-mclean-uk4z6?file=/src/App.tsx) (come with the solutions above)

Comment: Whatever pattern you're trying to build here seems overly complicated and abstract. We might be able to figure out this specific problem but why exactly are you structuring it this way? What are you trying to accomplish? What is your end goal?

Comment: @jered I want to create a Component, let say a component A that accept another component as props, let say component B, end result is A has both props of A and props of B

currently solution 1 works fine I think, just want to know is there a better way of doing so

Comment: It seems like you're doing some kind of higher order component, but it's not clear why. The use cases of a HOC are pretty narrow. It's likely that you'd do perfectly well with a simpler component composition pattern - simply pass components to each other as children and let React do its thing.

Comment: Your example is also a bit confusing, what is `abc` versus `{a, b, c}`? Can you make your example a bit more true to real life, or just rename things so it's more clear what's going on?

Comment: I am asking this out of curiosity, consider this a theoretical question, the purpose is to combine A and B props types when A accept B as a prop